# Is there a function to remove spaces in the middle of strings in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a string field that stores a postal code in a MongoDb collection.
Currently, each postal code has the following format:

> A5A 5A5

There is a single space between A5A and 5A5.

Is there a mongo function that I can use to remove this middle space?

For example, after applying the function, the postal code should appear as

> A5A5A5

And is there a query that can be made to do this for all documents in the collection?  So far I can only find the trim() function which does leading and trailing spaces, which doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `update` version.  Important to use the pipeline version of the `update` operator.  Practically the same logic as above except it has extra defense for more than one space showing up in between tokens:

```
var r =
[
 {name: "ADA DDD"}
 ,{name: "ADD  222"}
 ,{name: "ADD   333"}
]
db.foo.insert(r);

rc = db.foo.update({}, // no predicate; update all                                
   [ {$set: {name: {$reduce: {
                       input: {$split: ["$name"," "]}, // chop up by spaces       
                       initialValue: "", // init value is empty string            
                       in: {$concat: [ "$$value",
                               // if item is a space, append blank else           
                               // append the item                                 
                               {$cond: [ {$eq:["$$this", " "]}, "", "$$this" ] } ]
                               }
                           }}
                   }}
               ],
           {multi:true});
```

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB 4.4 offers the [$replaceAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/#replaceall-aggregation) string operator.  You could use that in the pipeline form of update or aggregation such as:

```
{
    $addFields: {
      postalCode: {
        $replaceAll: {
          input: "$postalCode",
          find: " ",
          replacement: ""
        }
      }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RFDDUqO-Yta)

Answer (score 1):

[You could use this:](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I7w3-Kp68ZG)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$addFields": {
    key: {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$split": [
            "$key",
            " "
          ]
        },
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          $concat: [
            "$$value",
            "$$this"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

- Split on spaces " "
- Use reduce to concatenate the values of the resulting array

If you need to updateMany, the pipeline works just fine inside update.